# Retrieve Quick View Form Value - Dynamics CRM JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, webresource

For a certain aspect of functionality, I require the need to pull a value from a quick view form on an entity "Course request" form. The quick view form is of the "programme" entity and includes details on Member and Non-member price.

I need to retrieve the "member price" value and set a corresponding field on the parent form to this value. I have the below code to do this, however this does not seem to work.

Quick View Form is called: Course: Programme Details - Quick View

```
function getPrice(){
    
    if (Xrm.Page.getControl('Course: Programme Details - Quick View_Course: Programme Details - Quick View_programme_MemberPrice') != null)
    {
            var priceQuickControl = Xrm.Page.getControl('Course: Programme Details - Quick View_Course: Programme Details - Quick View_programme_MemberPrice');
            var price = priceQuickControl.getAttribute("memberprice").getValue();
            //var newEmailfield = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("MemberPrice");
            var priceCourseRequest = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("memberprice").setValue(price);
            console.log(priceCourseRequest);

    }
    else{
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this a dupe - https://stackoverflow.com/q/65921494/7920473?

Comment: Any follow up questions?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using Name of Quick view form instead of label, as name cannot have space like you used.

Also, you may need to use `isLoaded` method to ensure the complete rendering and `setTimeout` for retry. [Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/reference/formcontext-ui-quickforms/isloaded)

```
function getAttributeValue(executionContext) {
    var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();
    var quickViewControl = formContext.ui.quickForms.get("<QuickViewControlName>");
    if (quickViewControl != undefined) {
        if (quickViewControl.isLoaded()) {
            // Access the value of the attribute bound to the constituent control
            var myValue = quickViewControl.getControl(0).getAttribute().getValue();
            console.log(myValue);
            
            // Search by a specific attribute present in the control       
            var myValue2 =  quickViewControl.getControl().find(control => control.getName() == "<AttributeSchemaName>").getAttribute().getValue();
            console.log(myValue2);
            
            return;
        }
        else {
            // Wait for some time and check again
            setTimeout(getAttributeValue, 10, executionContext);
        }
    }
    else {
        console.log("No data to display in the quick view control.");
        return;
    }
}
```